# Shell saying that django_cleanup module I've installed don't exist

Tags: python, django

Like in title I've installed django_cleanup by using:

```
pip install django-cleanup
```

and put in INSTALLED_APPS:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django_cleanup',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.flatpages',
'shop',
'account',
'rest_framework',
]
```

but now when I'm trying to run test or server in shell then i get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_cleanup'
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/un1t/django-cleanup#configuration

The directions in the configuration section state this is the correct method to add to `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
   'django_cleanup.apps.CleanupConfig',
]
```

And I would add it at the end of the installed apps list, not at the head